# Class 'SqlFormatter' is missing CAKEPHP 3 DebugKit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've just installed the latest Debugkit from https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit.

Everything is working. However, when I clicked on the "SQL Log", the CakePHP logo keeps spinning. I tried to debug by opening up the console.log and saw an 500 error. It shows the below.

Error: Class 'SqlFormatter' not found
File /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/App/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Template/Element/sql_log_panel.ctp
Line: 24

From my understanding, SqlFormatter class is not found in sql_log_panel.ctp. How can I add/declare the SqlFormatter class?

Comment: Install it via composer, problem very likely solved then.

Comment: Sorry to ask, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md & http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp I highly recommen you to become familiar with composer, it is a standard tool for php developers for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install it via composer, problem very likely solved then.

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp

I highly recommend you to become familiar with composer, it is a standard tool for php developers for some time now. Composer will automatically install the dependencies for you.

Your second best option would be to download the SqlFormatter package manually from where ever it comes from and set your autoloading or include manually up.